# Website doesn't show html folder on webserver

Tags: html, visual-studio

I have deployed a web application to our web server via Visual studio. The problem is that the html folder in the wwwroot folder won't show up on the web page. However it is on the web server, meaning that it did get deployed.

[Folder in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T99ND.png)

[wwwroot folder on web server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGGgb.png)

[folders on web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FYGg.png)

Please help.

Comment: Have you created a website on IIS which points to your folder inside wwwroot?

Comment: I don't know what that means, how can I check?